# Slicing in a 2D Array in F# but similar to Matlab?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, c#-to-f#, f#-data

I was wondering if there is a way to use a list or an array of int as an index for slicing into a array to get a sub array in f#.

I know you can do the following

```
Arr2d.[*,1] or Arr2d.[1..5,1..2] etc...
```

But I was looking for something like in Matlab where you can write:

```
Arr2d([1;6;10],1) or Arr2d(1:10,[1;6;10])
```

Is it possible to do slicing like that in F#?

Thanks!

Here was my sample solution: (maybe not optimal but works)

```
let sampleMatrix = Array2D.init 10 5 (fun x y -> y)

val sampleMatrix : int [,] = [[0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
                              [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
                              [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
                              [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
                              [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
                              [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
                              [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
                              [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
                              [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
                              [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]]

let idxlist = [1;3;4]

let array2dColumnSlice (idxlist:list<int>) (data:'T[,]) = 
  let tmp = [|for i in idxlist -> data.[*,i]|] 
  Array2D.init tmp.[0].Length tmp.Length (fun x y -> tmp.[y].[x] )

let slice = array2dColumnSlice idxlist sampleMatrix

val slice : int [,] = [[1; 3; 4]
                       [1; 3; 4]
                       [1; 3; 4]
                       [1; 3; 4]
                       [1; 3; 4]
                       [1; 3; 4]
                       [1; 3; 4]
                       [1; 3; 4]
                       [1; 3; 4]
                       [1; 3; 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx), there is no additional slicing notation beyond what you have already found.

Answer (score 1):

For ranges only, it is possible, by wrapping Array2D with a sliceable type, or using the old [PowerPack](https://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/releases/view/99231)'s Matrix type.

See the docs here:
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx#sectionToggle6**

> You can use this slicing syntax for types that implement the element
>   access operators and overloaded GetSlice methods. For example, the
>   following code creates a Matrix type that wraps the F# 2D array,
>   implements an Item property to provide support for array indexing, and
>   implements three versions of GetSlice. If you can use this code as a
>   template for your matrix types, you can use all the slicing operations
>   that this section describes.

Comment: I don't think that allows for slicing similar to the second example given.